# C# Get nameof a property with the model extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, mvc-editor-templates

---

EDIT

I just noticed that when I tried to store the value of nameof(Model) it came in as "Model" but when I generated the TextBox the name field comes in as DateVerified.Model from this template. I'm super confused why this is happenning.

[image: Model Name]

---

I'm trying to get the name of a property without the . extension after it in order to do some dynamic binding for my Asp.Net Editor Templates but can't seem to get it to work.

**This is my template view,**

```
@model DateTime?

@Html.LabelFor(m => m)
<div class="input-group datepicker form-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </span>
    @Html.TextBox(nameof(Model), Model.HasValue ? 
Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : "", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

As you can see I have different date properties entering in this template and some can be null which is why I'm checking values instead of just using the @Html.TextBoxFor helper. This works great except the name of the property comes in as instances like,

```
DateVerified.Model
DateCreated.Model
```

This won't work for my model binding on postback since my properties are just named DateVerified or DateCreated. How can I get the name of these properties but without the extension?

Comment: `nameof(Model)` should give you `"Model"`, `nameof(Something.Model)` should still give you `"Model"`. Can you verify that it isn't something else tucking on DateVerified and DateCreated?

Comment: And if you actually want DateVerified, have you tried `nameof(DateVerified)` ? If you don't have that type, you're probably going to just do `"DateVerified"` directly.

Comment: The problem is that DateVerified in that instance is the Model so I can't ask directly for nameof(DateVerified). I'll see if I can get some extra data on this post.

Comment: Added extra information regarding the problem. You were right about it giving Model from nameof(Model) but the TextBox helper seems to rename it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I was being dumb. I changed this line,

```
@Html.TextBox(nameof(Model), Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : "", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

To this,

```
@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : "", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And the names of my date properties came in the way I wanted them to look for my Model Binding.